# How to manage the separate session for same browser Admin & Frontend in django

Tags: python, django

I'm looking for a way to separate the session handling for the admin part of a site and the frontend.

A person should be able to log in to the admin (only if he has is_staff and/or is_superuser).
He should have to be able to login with another username into frontend.

So basically it's like two separate sessions for the admin and frontend. 
Login/Logout and Permission-check functionality is not a problem, different sessions is the problem. Any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: According to django documentation(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-authentication-backends), it should be possible. If you can specify authentication backends that will process incoming requests without raising the `PermissionDenied` exception, you can use multiple authentication systems in same project

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can't do that unless you have a separate authentication system which is not provided by django. Means, you can use django's auth system for admin users and a separate auth system which for normal users. IMHO, its not very ideal solution if you don't have a separate auth system.

Alternativly, you can write a new middleware for this. In that middleware, you can check if the user is authenticated with an admin user, and if he/she is, then log him/her out of the application and redirect to login page.

Here is an example:

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout

class RestrictAdminUserInFrontend(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        if request.path.find("/admin/") == -1 and request.user.is_authenticated and request.user.is_superuser:
             logout(request)
             return redirect('login-page')
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```

And add that to [**`MIDDLEWARE`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/middleware/#activating-middleware) settings:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'other middlewares',
    'path.to.RestrictAdminUserInFrontend'
]
```

So, in this approach your admin users will be forced to login using normal user's username and password. But admin site and frontend will use same session.