# How to prevent django admin login and logout sessions from reflecting in actual website?

Tags: django, authentication, session, django-admin

I'm quite new to django.

I've made a website that makes use of **user auth** for *login, logout and registration*.

Whenever I log into the admin panel, it also gets reflected in the actual website. The admin account gets logged into the website on its own.

I know this is the default behaviour of the **django** auth system, but I want to separate the auth session of admin panel and the actual website.

How can I do so?

The screenshots below show the thing which I'm talking about.

Here I've logged into the **Admin** panel.

[image: admin panel]

The **Admin** account got logged into the website on its own by using the admin session..

[image: website home page]

I just want that both admin panel and website should have separate auth sessions and shouldn't be linked to each other.

The website is hosted online [here](https://shoponline-ca.herokuapp.com)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write middleware for this, to explicitly logout authenticated users in non-admin pages as suggested in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57357586/2135738

Comment: Ohkay.. that seems to be quite a lot of work than expected! I think I should stick to what I have now! Will look into this later! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue. So I just filtered is_staff = false to get the normal users for my project in my views.py and forced my admin to login page